# Most efficient arc for developing cross-browser support?

Tags: web-development, cross-browser

I'm curious to hear what approach people take to planning for cross-browser support when developing a website.

There are generally two approaches I've seen developers take in their workflow:

-optimize for webkit then apply hacks for IE7-9, or
-optimize for IE7-8 then apply newer features for IE9/webkit

Basically starting at the front of technology and working toward the back, or starting at the back of technology and working toward the front.

How do you do things? What advantages or disadvantage do you perceive in the different way of doing things wrt to developing cross-browser support?

Answer (score 1):

Working at the front and going toward the back later on is the best practice in my opinion. Working on optimization for current and widely used technology allows you to **publish now and rework later**. This is particularly effective if you have deadlines to meet. Looking at [top browser usage](http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_stats.asp) (Chrome17 at the forefront, Firefox 10, IE8, then all of the other browsers), you should start at the top and work your way down. Chrome17 has - as of 31.9% of all the browser market.

So, you can publish your webpage while appealing to the majority of browser users, then as time goes on you can work on optimization down the chain.

Answer (score 0):

I start with the standard and most modern ones. Firefox, Chrome, MSIE9 (10)

Then I fix MSIE8 (rarely I need fix for this), MSIE7

Older browsers (MSIE6, FF2) will get a completely different .css, or none at all: plain HTML

then mobile css, optimized only for smartphones (webkit 4xx+, mobile ie9, gecko 5+)

Answer (score 0):

I save old IEs for last, because there is always a chance the feature/site/project gets scrapped before you get to the end.